# Saving data with pickle and tkinter for later use

Tags: python, tkinter, pickle

This is my code:

```
import pickle
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

Game = Tk()

Gold = 0
Multiply = 1

def Save():
    with open('objs.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump([Gold, Multiply], f)

def Load():
    with open('objs.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)

def ClickButton():
    global Gold
    print(Gold)
    Gold +=1 * (Multiply)



Load()
GoldButton = Button(Game, height = 15, width = 25, text="Click!", command ClickButton, bg = "purple")
GoldButton.place(x = 160, y = 95)


save = Button(Game, height = 15, width = 25, text="Click to Save", command = Save)
save.place(x = 380, y = 95)


Game.resizable(width=False, height = False)
Game.geometry('700x450')
Game.title("Gold Farm")
```

What I want it to do:

- Load the variables "Gold" and "Multiply" from the Pickle file
- Save the new information to the file apon closure (Gold and Multiply)

The problem with it is that when  I reopen the program with the variables in the file, it just sets the Gold and Multiply to their default values regardless

Whats the problem here? How do I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're throwing away the data that you're loading. The `Load` function doesn't save the data to variables, it simply returns what was loaded.

You need to save the value you get back from `Load`:

```
try:
    Gold, Multiply = Load()
except IOError:
    Gold, Multiply = 0, 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. :) But I have another problem, it comes up with an error when the file doesent exist yet, or the files empty, how would I prevent this?

Comment: @Csarg 

`os.path.isfile(file)`